Asian martial arts movie with a ring
I remember seeing a movie when I was about 5-6 (1999-2000) about a kid who found a ring with powers that gave him martial art skills. Also, he had a mentor who showed him how to use the ring. It was something like Karate Kid but different.
I thought the mentor was played by an actor from Blade (when the vampires are gathered around the round table, I saw an old Asian man), but I am not sure because I couldn't find his name anywhere.

This sounds like The Power Within, a 1995 movie with a teenager who receives a ring that grants him magical martial arts skill:

Stan Dryer, a teen, afraid to even ask a girl to the prom, finds courage and extreme martial arts skill when he is given a ring by an old man

I haven't seen the movie, but IMDB seems to indicate that the old man is played by Gerald Okamura, who is also listed as playing an uncredited vampire in Blade.
